# Unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: runtime-error, vb.net-2010, streamwriter, unhandled

I'm having trouble with this block of code. The StreamWriter creates the .txt document and puts it in the projects bin folder, but when I run the program, I get an error that says:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll**
the process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process.

There are no other programs running on my computer, so I'm not sure what other process could be using it. Here's my code, thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub saveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveButton.Click
    Dim voteWriter As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim vote As String

    voteWriter = IO.File.AppendText("warrenHS.txt")
    vote = Convert.ToString(canidateListBox.SelectedItem)

    voteWriter.Write(vote)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to close the stream after you are done with it.

```
voteWriter.Close()
```

Or you could use it in a using statement that will automatically close it at the end.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. There are many answers regarding other programs using the file, but in most cases it's just an unclosed stream.